# I want to do pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In my javascript,

```
$(".pagination").bootpag(
       {
           total: total_pages,
           page: 1,
           maxVisible: 10,
           leaps: true 
        }).on("page", function(event, num)
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#results").html('<div class="loading-indication" style="padding:10px;"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading...</div>');
                ajax_communicator("sample_ajax","page="+num+"&"+globalfield,"after_loaded");
            });
```

In my ajax page,

```
if(isset($_POST["page"]))
    {
        $page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
        if(!is_numeric($page_number))
        {
            die('Invalid page number!');
        } //incase of invalid page number
    }
    else
    {
        $page_number = 1;
        //print_r($page_number);
    }
```

I got the field, id and pagination footer also... but the records are shown in the same page..it doesn't get divided..plz tell me where am i go wrong in is code??